# How to this error ? utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 32887: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOO4F.png)

Hello. I am trying to open this file which is in .txt format but it gives me an error.

Comment: share the .txt content

Comment: Please edit your question to provide your code in text format, rather than an [image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes when you don't have uniform files you have to by specific with the correct encoding,
You should indicate it in function open for example,

```
with open(‘file.txt’, encoding = ‘utf-8’) as f:
    etc
```

also you can detect the file encoding like this:

```
from chardet import detect

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    rawdata = f.read()
    enc = detect(rawdata)['encoding']

with open(‘file.txt’, encoding = enc) as f:
    etc
```

Result:

```
>>> from chardet import detect
>>>
>>> with open('test.c', 'rb') as f:
...     rawdata = f.read()
...     enc = detect(rawdata)['encoding']
...
>>> print(enc)
ascii
```

Python 3.7.0

Comment: The exception message suggests the file is already being opened with UTF-8 encoding, but that the actual contents is in some other encoding.

Comment: The message actually suggests that it found and utf8 and cant decode automatically. Python is very strict with this thing. But in any case the thing is that you have to be sure the encoding of the file, and be specific. This will be very annoying sometimes.

Comment: Um, yes? That's what I was trying to say. Your answer however, is telling the questioner to specify `'utf-8'` as the encoding, when that's probably already what they have (or what they're getting by default if they don't specify it).

Comment: You may have a point , but the thing is that you will have this error very frequent and need to know the correct encoding, you are right but sometimes you will have this file in utf-8 and a little variation will throw the exception